# Vue.js: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I'm building my first app with Vue.js 2, and can't figure out the error.

I'm using full build (`webpack.config.js`):

```
 resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js',
            "vueRouter$": "vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
```

My html:

```
<div id="app">
    <adv-component></adv-component>
</div>
```

My `main.js`:

```
const Vue = require('vue');
var vueComponent = require('./component.vue');
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app', 
    data: {

    },
    // Local registration
    components: {
        'adv-component': vueComponent,
    }
});
```

`component.vue`:

```
<template id='asd'>
    <div>
        Hello Single File Component!
    </div> 
</template>

<script>
    export default {     
        data () {
            return 0;
        }
    }  
</script>
```

The error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <AdvComponent>
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Can you remove maybe the ` id='asd'` from your template tags?

Comment: @samayo Tried. Didn't work. This was me trying to fix the issue in the first place — read somewhere that the is necessary

Comment: Are you using any [vuejs-template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/)? | Also, have you tried https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1882#issuecomment-344504483 ?

Comment: @yuriy636 Wow! Thanks. `default` did the trick. If you could put it as an answer and also explain what `default` does (I'm completely inexperienced in `webpack` and related), I will gladly accept this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Vue component is usually exported with `export default { /* ... */}` so it facilitates the default import like `import Component from './component.vue'`(ES6 syntax)

**When using `require()` (CommonJS) you have to specify you are requiring the `default` export:**

```js
var vueComponent = require('./component.vue').default;
```

Comment: what is the solution, if I am using RequireJS instead of CommonJS?