# "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined" in Vue, despite using full compiler bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

I am trying to develop a re-usable Vue component. It is setup to build using webpack, and then a demo page loads the full Vue compiler and this compiled bundle onto a page. However, on loading the page I receive the following error, despite having included the Vue compiler.

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Cwl>
       <Root>
```

I would have thought that the vue-loader would have set the `template` field of the `cwl` component, and I would have thought that the Vue version I added to my page would include the compiler. What am I missing here?

---

The code in question can be seen at this [GitHub URL](https://github.com/TMiguelT/vue-cwl/commit/305e16e9c3c76170b8839210a00c4d791da194b5). Simply clone the repo, run `webpack`, start a server with `http-server`, and then browse to http://localhost:8080/demo/.

For reference, my demo HTML page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="vue" class="container container-fluid">
    <cwl
            cwl-url="https://rawgit.com/rabix/cwl-svg/master/cwl-samples/fastqc.json"
    ></cwl>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/index.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.config.devtools = true;
    Vue.config.debug = true;
    new Vue({
        el: '#vue',
        components: {
            cwl: vue_cwl
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",

    // Read files from js/src
    entry: './cwl.vue',

    // Output everything into the static folder
    output: {
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        path: path.resolve("dist/"),
        filename: "index.js",
        library: 'vue_cwl'
    },

    externals: {
        vue: 'vue'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [require('babel-preset-env')]
                    }
                },

            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                exclude: ["node_modules"],
                use: {
                    loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
                    options: {
                        useBabel: true
                    }
                }
            },
            {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]},
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".vue"],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
    }
};
```

Comment: I have no clue how to fix this, because I always used the webpack template from the vue-cli. In that way everything works out of the box and you never even have to look at webpack configs. Maybe give it a try? https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli

Comment: What's strange is my webpack.config looks a lot like the `vue-cli` one: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js. But I'll give it a go anyway

Comment: Yeah, really don't know. I try to avoid configuring development environments as much as possible. In my opinion that should be something that just works. The vue webpack and webpack-simple templates just work :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `console.log(vue_cwl)` you can see there is a `default` property which contains the actual Vue component. Change your code to use the `default` property as the component:

```
components: {
    cwl: vue_cwl.default
}
```

From [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266500/vue-js-failed-to-mount-component-template-or-render-function-not-defined/48267716):

> A Vue component is usually exported with `export default { /* ... */}`
>   so it facilitates the default import like `import Component from './component.vue'`(ES6 syntax)
>
> **When using require() (CommonJS) you have to specify you are requiring
>   the default export**

In your case you are including directly the component via `<script>` but the concept remains.